# Проблема с выводом Кириллицы в KIVY

Tags: python, kivy

#### KV file.###[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу найти решение проблемы с выводом Русского языка.
Если используем Кириллицу, киви выводит непонятные символы

```
TextInput:
    hint_text:"input F.I.O"
    id: fio_input_id
    font_size: 30
TextInput:
    hint_text:"input GOROD"
    font_size: 30
TextInput:
    hint_text:"НОМЕР"
    font_size: 30
    input_filter: 'int'**
```

Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Для начала переведите свой вопрос на русский.

Comment: Спасибо, готово

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, ваш код -- так проще всего воспроизвести проблему

Comment: gil9red, что необходимо, .py или .kv ?

Comment: @АртемКоваленко, и то, и то. А так, у вас кодировка `kv` скорее всего `windows-1251`, а нужно `utf-8`

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('kv_file.kv', encoding='utf-8') as kv_file:
    kv_file.read()
```